# Kotlin. Basic JavaFX application

Tags: javafx, kotlin

Trying out Kotlin lang and I had an impression that it is compatible with Java and therefore with JavaFX and i tried following:

```
public object TestKt: Application() {

    public override fun start(stage: Stage){
        val pane= Pane()
        val scene=Scene(pane,200.0,200.0)
        stage.scene = scene
        stage.show()

    }
    @JvmStatic public fun main(args: Array<String>){
        launch()
    }
}
```

this is basically same as Java's

```
public class Test extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage)  {
        Pane pane=new Pane();
        Scene scene=new Scene(pane, 200,200);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    public static  void  main(String[] args){
        launch();
    }
}
```

but Kotlin gives an error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to construct Application instance: class Test

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The code samples you provided are not equivalent: an [`object` declaration](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-declarations) in Kotlin is a singleton, so it only has one instance constructed by calling the private constructor when the class is initialized. JavaFX is trying to call the constructor of the class reflectively but fails because the constructor is private as it should be.

What you may be looking instead is a simple class declaration, with the `main` in its [companion object](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#companion-objects). If no explicit constructors are declared, Kotlin, like Java, will generate a default one, allowing JavaFX to instantiate the application:

```
class Test : Application() {
    override fun start(stage: Stage) {
        ...
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun main(args: Array<String>) {
            launch(Test::class.java)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also just plop the `fun main()` bit directly in the top-level scope, too.

Comment: It worked a little better, but still had: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error: class TestKt$Companion is not a subclass of javafx.application.Application

Comment: I think you should use this method of Application: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Application.html#launch(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String...). In Kotlin that would be `launch(TestKt::class.java)`

Comment: Now it worked, thank You) Can You please also update Your initial answer so it would be complete? Спасибо)

Comment: This works, but it does not pass the program arguments to the Application. I personally use `@JvmStatic fun main(vararg args:String){launch(Main::class.java,*args);}`

Comment: @Max Nope, that doesn't work since you can't call `launch()`

Comment: @m0skit0 uh, sure you can. I was proposing exactly what @jenglert ended up posting, except that I would import `Application.launch`.

Comment: @Max Dude, I was just using `launch()` and [you can't call it](https://ibb.co/bsuVcm), I had to resort to `Application.launch(MyApplication::class.java, *args)`.

Comment: @m0skit0 Your FXMain method doesn't have a static `launch` method. All I'm saying is, if you do what's shown in @jenglert's example, but also include `import javafx.application.Application.launch` at the top, then you can say `launch(MyApplication::class.java, *args)`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. In my case I already had the code like yours, the only problem was what I was passing to the `launch` function.

Answer (score 44):

```
class MyApplication : Application() {

   override fun start(primaryStage: Stage) {

   }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
   Application.launch(MyApplication::class.java, *args)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is simple method to perform launch of Java FX Application

```
class MyApplication: Application(){
    override fun start(primaryStage: Stage?){
        //You code here
    }

    companion object{
        @JvmStatic
        fun main(args: Array<String>){
            launch(MyApplication::class.java, *args)
        }
    }
}
```