# Can't run JavaFX - Kotlin app

Tags: javafx, kotlin, desktop

I can't run my javafx - kotlin app.

My Starter class

```
class Starter : Application() {

  override fun start(primaryStage: Stage?) {
      val root : Parent = FXMLLoader.load(javaClass.getResource("view/main.fxml"))
      primaryStage?.title = "Title"
      primaryStage?.scene = Scene(root)
      primaryStage?.show()
  }

  fun main(args: Array<String>) {
      launch(args)
  }
}
```

I can't pass the param "args" to "launch" method because compiler says:

> Error:(19, 9) Kotlin: None of the following functions can be called
>   with the arguments supplied:  public open fun launch(p0: Class!, vararg p1: String!): Unit defined in
>   javafx.application.Application public open fun launch(vararg p0:
>   String!): Unit defined in javafx.application.Application

If I trying call "launch" method without params I have following Exception

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
>     ... 5 more

Comment: `primaryStage` will never be null, remove the `?` from the type and the variable method calls.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34833258/320399

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use spread operator

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    Application.launch(Starter::class.java, *args)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. I also need to add a "companion object" block to my "main" method. `companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun main(args: Array<String>) {
            launch(Starter::class.java, *args)
        }
    }`

Comment: you don't need the companion object. Just do as shown above and it will work.

Comment: Just don't put the `main` function inside the class, leave it outside.